# How to call a thymeleaf modal fragment from a javascript generated link?

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I have a javascript function that renders a table from an ajax call.

The row rendering bit is:

```
function buildTable(id) {
    trHTML = null;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: siteroot + "apiURL" + id,
            data: {},
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    trHTML +=
                        '<tr>' +
                            '<td>' + data[i].value +
                            '<a class="pull-right" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-modal" > ' +
                            '<span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>' +
                            '</a>' +
                            '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + data[i].text + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + data[i].description + '</td>' +
                        '</tr>';
                }
                $('#resourceTable').append('<tbody>' + trHTML + '</tbody>');

                },
                error: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg.responseText);
                }
        });
    }
```

And the modal is defined as:

```
<div th:replace="../../modals/modal"></div>
```

The issue I am facing is that the link is here on the rendered table, but when I click it, the modal does not come on.

What am I not seeing here?

Comment: I think the you have assigned event to the modal before rendering. Please try after and let me if it works.

Comment: I have edited the question to add the full javascript function. The `<div th:replace ... />` is the last part of the template.